# page crash when draw a google chart after ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

i want create a chart when data recive from ajax , when i call google api for draw chart on callback function of ajax page crash and display a white page with some javascript tag like below

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/uds/?file=visualization&amp;v=1.0&amp;packages=corechart" type="text/javascript"></script><link href="https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/ce05bcf99b897caacb56a7105ca4b6ed/ui+en.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"><script src="https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/ce05bcf99b897caacb56a7105ca4b6ed/format+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.I.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and remove my old page structure . my ajax function are some thing like below :

```
$.get("stocker.php",{data:mydata} ,function(data) {
function drawVisualization() {
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'times');
  data.addColumn('number', 'price');
  data.addColumn('number', 'volume');
  for(i = 0; i < times.length; i++)
    data.addRow([times[i], prices[i],vols[i]]);
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
        $(function(){
    new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('daychart')).
    draw(data, {});     
}) });}
drawVisualization();}
```

what is the reason of white page , and what's the mistake

Comment: What's "white page"? do you see something like an error in the console or do you get the infamous "White Page Error: White Page. At line (not telling you) Stack trace: White page in white page?"

Comment: no console error ... just all page element clear ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must first load a empty template of chart in your page and when get new data with ajax you just change data of that empty hart and redraw it . your problem is you draw chart in ajax callback .

Answer (score 0):

Page elements clear due to a quirk in the google loader.  When called from inside another function, the loader behaves differently, unless you specify the callback inline, instead of via the `setOnLoadCallback` method.  That issue aside, the way your code is structured virtually guarantees that errors will the thrown, because you are not waiting for the callback before trying to use API elements.  There are a handful of different ways you can handle this properly.  In all cases, I would suggest loading the API before making your AJAX call, but you especially need to do this if you will be making multiple AJAX calls (as the API will load only once, the callback will only fire the first time it is loaded).  Here is an example you can work from:

```
function drawVisualization () {
    $.get("stocker.php", {data:mydata}, function(data) {
        // this var data line overwrites the data from your AJAX call, so you should change variable names
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'times');
        data.addColumn('number', 'price');
        data.addColumn('number', 'volume');
        // where do times, prices, and vols come from?
        for(i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
            data.addRow([times[i], prices[i], vols[i]]);
        }
        new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('daychart')).draw(data, {});
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart'], callback: drawVisualization});
```